# Strange issue when changing toolbar programmatically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I'm having some troubles when i try to change **ToolBar** programmatically.

When i change **ToolBar** title from code, and when i run program on real device my toolbar title is "MyAppName @2131558664", but i set only "MyAppName"

Also i have **ViewPager** with fragments, in one of the fragments i getting toolbar and change toolbar menu(Add **SearchView** ), when i also start program and open **SearchView** my query also contains this "@2131558664". Why it happens? How can i fix it? 
Thank for responces

**Toolbar.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/MyToolBar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**MyToolBar theme:**

```
<style name="MyToolBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:text">@style/TextAppearance.Widget.Event.Toolbar.Title</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>
```

Snippet where i change **ToolBar:**

```
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("MyAppName");
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you wrote "android:text" and instead of text you passed a theme and not text and because you refer to an object and not a string you get that  - @2131558664 in addition.
Since you added that piece of code to set the title you actually concatenating two strings.
Its kinda like writing:

```
setTitle("my app" + "@2131558664");
```

for reference if you will look up your R file (as in R.id.my_textView) for example you will see a big file filled with these:

```
int attr actionBarTheme 0x7f010060
int attr actionBarWidgetTheme 0x7f010061
```

So I'm guessing that the text "@2131558664" referring to the id of that theme.

few things you also need to know:

1.each id in the R file is actually an int even if it has a letter in it.

2.if you will use "toString()" method on any widget like TextView or anything similar you will get a similar result unless its a string then you will get the string itself.

3.the R file isn't editable by the user and that why you have to use the find view by id method which actually connecting the object by the id to the object you are creating.

A good example for it is getting text from and Edit text

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
//EditText - this is the object you create
//R.id.editText - thats the int in the memory


et.getText();
//XXXXX this is thee wrong way to get a string from edit text since
//its return and editable and if you will pass it to a text view you
//will get the int with represent the id in the memory. 



et.getText().toString();
//this is the right way to get a string from an edit text since it
//return a string
```

You should try it, just for fun and knowledge =D

Comment: Thanks for responce! the problem solved after i remove <item name="android:text">@style/TextAppearance.Widget.Event.Toolbar.Title</item>

Comment: @Ololoking I edited my answer. it will help you figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your string to string.xml file and use `getResources().getString(R.string.appTitle);`
to read the string from string.xml.

also try to clean your project and check for anything missing or error on xml or 
resource file

Comment: Thanks for responce! This didnt help.Problem is solved ,pls check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have solved my problem. 
This strange text dissapear when i remove

`<item name="android:text">@style/TextAppearance.Widget.Event.Toolbar.Title</item>`

I dont why its happens, if anyone know pls explain me.